# Sync Azure SQL Database with Azure Cosmos DB MongoDB API

Tags: azure, .net-core

I have one of the requirement to sync Azure SQL database with Azure cosmos Db. I am specially looking for mongodb api but solution for any other api would be helpful. Sync should be able to cover all tables with insert, update, and delete operation.

Comment: you re gonna have to write some code and get yours row from sql to cosmos

Comment: look into Azure Data Factory

Comment: Firstly i tried with azure data factory but it's not possible to handle delete operation and we need to keep track of lastmodifytime to ensure no redundancy. It is scheduled on time basis. I need trigger base solution something like when we insert, update and delete row in table, it should automatically sync to cosmos db.

Comment: i found striim tool. still i didn't get success. any help would be appreciated

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution?

Comment: I am able to sync the data using striim tool but it is paid tool.